# Compute $d(\log(S_t))$ using Ito's Formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

We are given the following:

d$S_t$ = $\sin(S_t)t^2dt + e^{\sqrt{S_t}-t}dB_t$

And are asked to compute several different things, one of which is $d \log(S_t).$

If I'm understanding Ito's formula correctly, which I may not be, from the $dS_t$ given, we know:

(1) $f''(S_t) = 2t^2\sin(S_t)$, and

(2) $f'(S_t) = e^{\sqrt{S_t}-t}$

But then how do you determine $S_t$ to compute log($S_t$) and it's first and second derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

$S_t$ is an Itō process, so you can apply the [Itō-Doeblin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D%27s_lemma#Mathematical_formulation_of_It.C5.8D.27s_lemma) to $f(t,x)=\log x.$ Therefore

$$d(\log(S_t))=\frac {1}{S_t}dS_t-\frac{1}{2S_t^2}dS_tdS_t$$

Note that $dB_tdB_t=dt,$ and $dtdB_t=0=dt^2, $ so $dS_tdS_t=e^{2(\sqrt{S_t}-t)}dt.$

Thus

$$d(\log(S_t))=(\frac{t^2\sin S_t}{S_t}-\frac{e^{2(\sqrt{S_t}-t)}}{2S_t^2})dt +\frac{e^{\sqrt{S_t}-t}}{S_t}dB_t.$$